# creating a file name in c program causing a seg fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, buffer

The is a struct in my program called `prv_instance_t` which contains an `experiment_id` as defined here.

From this `experiment_id` variable I want to create another variable called `serial_log` which stores serial data from a UART. I want this handled in a thread. I create the filename for the serial data by appending `"_serial_log.txt"` to the `experiment_id` as below.

```
int function() { 

prv_serial_logging_thread_params_t serial_logging_thread_params;
targetP = (prv_instance_t *)lwm2m_list_find(objectP->instanceList, instanceId);
```

I then create a thread using pthread.

I'm getting a seg fault, could I be creating the filename in a better way, maybe I am causing a buffer overflow?

Answer (score 2):

`serial_logging_thread_params` is a *local* variable. It will go out of scope and disappear once the function returns. If that happens while the thread is still running, then the pointer to the structure will become invalid.

Allocate the structure dynamically using `malloc`.